# How to adjust the johnon-neyman plot in?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I plotted the johnon-neyman plot using the sim_slopes() function of the "interactions"package. But I want to adjust the appearance of the graph : ① horizontal and vertical headings ② sthe scale values of the vertical and horizontal coordinates ③ and delete the bold black line "Range of observed data"

```
mod <- lm(sorry~ preciseage*group, data = RAWdata)
sim_slopes(mod, pred = group, modx = preciseage, jnplot = TRUE,confint = TRUE )
```

I tried two methods offered by others, and neither solved the problem(They all report an error: the binary column operator has non-numeric arguments),and the code templates for both are as follows：

```
#first
mod$plot + xlab("my x label") + ylab("my y label")

mod[["plot"]] +
  labs(title = "My new Johnson-Neyman Plot title", x = "My new x axis", y = "My new y axis")
```

As a new R language learning, there are always a variety of problems, I really need your help, thank you!

I plotted the johnon-neyman plot using the sim_slopes() function of the "interactions"package. But I want to adjust the appearance of the graph : ① horizontal and vertical headings ② sthe scale values of the vertical and horizontal coordinates ③ and delete the bold black line "Range of observed data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I don't have the sample data I'll show you an example with the iris data.

Data and libaries:

```
library(interactions)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
```

Example linear regression:

```
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length, data = iris)
my_sim_slopes <- sim_slopes(
  mod,
  pred = Petal.Length,
  modx = Sepal.Width,
  jnplot = TRUE,
  confint = TRUE
)
```

I could verify that the class of the plot object is a ggplot, so I loaded the `ggplot2` library.

```
class(my_sim_slopes[["jnplot"]])
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

assign the plot to an object:

```
plot <- my_sim_slopes[["jnplot"]]
```

the bottom bold line seems to be built on layers 7 and 8, to remove it set it as NULL:

```
plot[["layers"]][c(7, 8)] <- NULL
```

in the end, as it is a ggplot object, it can be customised with its functions:

```
plot +
  labs(title = "My new Johnson-Neyman Plot title",
       x = "My new x axis",
       y = "My new y axis") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:7, limits = c(0, 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 12))
```

original image:
[image: original image]

modified image:
[image: modified image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You have described each step very clearly. I would also like to ask you, the bottom line in bold is on the 7th or 8th floor. How do you know this information?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the recognition. If the answer was helpful, please mark it as correct. As for the bottom line, it can be deduced by inspecting the object since layer elements 7 and 8 in their "constructor" sub-elements contain respectively `geom_hline`(horizontal line, commonly used for it) and `geom_segment` (similar to the horizontal line but more easily customisable by position). Under this suspicion, it was enough to remove these two elements to confirm that it was indeed the black line in the bottom.